# parse out hidden text from docx

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a rich text editor in MVC 3 app.  It works fine unless the user tries to copy text from microsoft word and paste into the editor.  When this happens I get extra hidden characters like this

```
<!--[if gte vml 1]><v:shapetype
 id="_x0000_t75" coordsize="21600,21600" o:spt="75" o:preferrelative="t"
 path="m@4@5l@4@11@9@11@9@5xe" filled="f" stroked="f">
 <v:stroke joinstyle="miter"/>
 <v:formulas>
  <v:f eqn="if lineDrawn pixelLineWidth 0"/>
  <v:f eqn="sum @0 1 0"/>
  <v:f eqn="sum 0 0 @1"/>
  <v:f eqn="prod @2 1 2"/>
  <v:f eqn="prod @3 21600 pixelWidth"/>
  <v:f eqn="prod @3 21600 pixelHeight"/>
  <v:f eqn="sum @0 0 1"/>
  <v:f eqn="prod @6 1 2"/>
  <v:f eqn="prod @7 21600 pixelWidth"/>
  <v:f eqn="sum @8 21600 0"/>
  <v:f eqn="prod @7 21600 pixelHeight"/>
  <v:f eqn="sum @10 21600 0"/>
 </v:formulas>
 <v:path o:extrusionok="f" gradientshapeok="t" o:connecttype="rect"/>
 <o:lock v:ext="edit" aspectratio="t"/>
</v:shapetype><v:shape id="Picture_x0020_1" o:spid="_x0000_i1025" type="#_x0000_t75"
 style='width:34.5pt;height:20.25pt;visibility:visible;mso-wrap-style:square'>
</v:shape><![endif]-->
```

I want to parse all this out before saving the input into the db.  right now I am using regex to find all text in between `'<!--'`  and `'-->'`  that seems to be working , but I feel this is not the best way , and I am not sure if the hidden stuff from a docx file is always formatted exactly like this.  Is there a better way to get rid of this extra hidden stuff?

Comment: other than the fact these look like processing instructions that manipulate the content itself, for which there are plenty of better ways, if you focus on the fact you're procssing a string you're doing it right.  Just that processing OpenXML through xml comments seems a bit archaic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`docx` is using an `OpenXML` format, so you can try to use any `xml parser`. For example, for `c# 3.5 and higher`, you can use Linq-To-Xml and this is how you find all of your comments:

```
var document = XDocument.Load("test.xml");

var comments =  from node in document.Elements().DescendantNodesAndSelf()
        where node.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Comment
        select node as XComment;
```

Comment: This *is* a more 'proper' approach (+1) but I'd be concerned about its performance compared to regex and to it being more error-prone as compared to regex.

Comment: That seems to work , I'll have to look into it to see performance difference